# help with font for my phd thesis

Tags: fonts, times

I have one question for you..I have tried a lot by my self but with no results. I am doing my phd thesis, and I working on this latex example as below.. But I think the font is not 12pt and is not times new roman. could you help me figure it out please?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book} 
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{times}
{\fontfamily{times}}
\geometry{lmargin=1.25in,rmargin=1.25in,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools,lineno,graphicx,textcomp,booktabs,url,setspace,xcolor,soul,eurosym}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hipoteza}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{subhyp} 
\let\savedc@hyp\c@hyp
\newenvironment{subhyp}
{%
    \setcounter{subhyp}{0}%
    \stepcounter{hyp}%
    \edef\saved@hyp{\thehyp}% Save the current value of hyp
    \let\c@hyp\c@subhyp     % Now hyp is subhyp
    \renewcommand{\thehyp}{\saved@hyp\alph{hyp}}%
}
{}
\newcommand{\normhyp}{%
    \let\c@hyp\savedc@hyp % revert to the old one
    \renewcommand\thehyp{\arabic{hyp}}%
} 
\makeatother
\usepackage{multirow,listings,setspace,latexsym,keyval,ifthen,moreverb,lscape,forest}
\graphicspath{{fig/}}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[]{microtype}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[vskip=-\parskip]{quoting}
\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\newcounter{notelabelcount}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
 %activate={true,nocompatibility},final,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.25cm}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.5cm}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes,arrows,intersections,shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.new} % LATEX and plain TEX when using TikZ
\tikzset{>=latex}

\newif\ifpienumberinlegend
\pgfkeys{/number in legend/.code=
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\ifpienumberinlegend
    \csname if#1\endcsname
    \ifpienumberinlegend
    \let\legendbeforenumber\beforenumber
    \let\legendafternumber\afternumber
    \def\beforenumber##1\afternumber{}%
    \fi,
    /number in legend/.default=true
}

\usepackage{chemfig} 
\usepackage[]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[indention=0.5cm,labelsep=colon,font={rm},labelfont={rm}]{caption}
\usepackage[indention=0.5cm,font={rm},labelfont={rm}]{subcaption}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.90} %not always visible on a dell screen!!!
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancypagestyle{frontmatter}{%    
    \fancyhf{}  
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\textsf{ \thepage}} 
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \fancyhead{}
        \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\textsf{ \thepage}}
    } 
}
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%    
    \fancyhf{}  
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\nouppercase{\small \textrm{\leftmark}}}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\textrm{ \thepage}} 
}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\newcounter{letternum}
\newcounter{lettersum}
\setcounter{lettersum}{13}
\newlength{\thumbtopmargin}
\setlength{\thumbtopmargin}{1cm}
\newlength{\thumbbottommargin}
\setlength{\thumbbottommargin}{1cm}
\newlength{\thumbheight}
\pgfmathsetlength{\thumbheight}{%
(\paperheight-\thumbtopmargin-\thumbbottommargin)/\value{lettersum}}

\newlength{\thumbwidth}
\setlength{\thumbwidth}{1.5cm}

\tikzset{
   thumb/.style={
%   draw=black,
  fill=light-gray,
   text=black,
   minimum height=\thumbheight, %\thumbheight,
   text width=\thumbwidth,
    outer sep=0pt,%   outer sep=10pt,
   font=\sffamily\Huge,
}
}
\newcommand{\oddthumb}[1]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node [thumb,text centered,anchor=north east,] at ($%
            (current page.north east)-%
            (0,\thumbtopmargin+\value{letternum}*\thumbheight)%
        $) {#1};
   \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\eventhumb}[1]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node [thumb,text centered,anchor=north west,] at ($%
            (current page.north west)-%
            (0,\thumbtopmargin+\value{letternum}*\thumbheight)%
        $) {#1};
   \end{tikzpicture}
}
% create a new command to set a new lettergroup
\newcommand{\lettergroup}[1]{%
\fancyhead[LO]{\oddthumb{#1}}%
\fancyhead[RE]{\eventhumb{#1}}%
\fancypagestyle{chapterstart}{%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhf{}
    \chead{\oddthumb{#1}}% chapters start only on odd pages
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\textsf{ \thepage}} %\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\textsf{Page \thepage}}
  }
    \thispagestyle{chapterstart}
\stepcounter{letternum}%
}


\usepackage[numbib,nottoc]{tocbibind}   %numbib

%\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\usepackage[]{natbib} %numbers,sort&compress
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap} %Sonny
\usepackage[]{cleveref} % load cleveref after hyperref

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} 

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{P\"ermbledhje}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Lista e Figurave}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Lista e Tabelave}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliografia}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Kapitulli}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabela}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Sh\"enime}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][1em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}%
   \def\chapquote@author{#2}%
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax%
   \itshape}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill--\ \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} 

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{frontmatter}
\lstset{language=Perl}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document} 

\chapter{}
\section{}

\chapter{}
\section

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading `tgbonum` makes `TeX Gyre Bonum`( an `ITC Bookman` clone) the default font, then `times`does the same for, well,  `times`, and last `lmodern`does it for `Latin Modern`. Load a single package. Incidentally, in LaTeX, the names of  font families uses a three-letter code, not the full name of the font. For Adobe Times, it is `\fontfamily{ptm}`.

Furthermore, this package is obsolete and doesn't manage maths fonts. It is recommended to load `newtxtext, newtxmath`, based on `TeX Gyre Termes`, a Times clone, which is much more complete – in particular it has true small caps.

Answer (score 1):

If you load `lmodern` after `times`, you will get Latin Modern fonts.

Comment: thank you.. can I ask an other question for this same example. I would like that when making a new paragraph it should begin slightly on the right of the previous paragraph..do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @KlodiGj -- the other question you wish to ask won't be found by many people because it is unrelated to the original question.  please ask a new question.